# Errors thrown when attemtping to play soung in Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing

Making a Swing application in which a user selects an audio file using a radio button and plays it using the Play button. The GUI class call the method from a custom audio handler class. The audio files are in a package called audio. The following errors are thrown after sound selection and the user clicks the Play button:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(AudioStream.java:63)
at my.quotesbutton.Player.fear(Player.java:18)
at my.quotesbutton.QuotesButtonUI.jButton3ActionPerformed(QuotesButtonUI.java:221)
at my.quotesbutton.QuotesButtonUI.access$000(QuotesButtonUI.java:16)
at my.quotesbutton.QuotesButtonUI$1.actionPerformed(QuotesButtonUI.java:66)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

The GUI class code as follows:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){

                Player play = new Player();
            try {
                play.fear();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QuotesButtonUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){

        }
        else if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()){

        }
        else if (jRadioButton4.isSelected()){

        }
        else if (jRadioButton5.isSelected()){

        }
        else if (jRadioButton6.isSelected()){

        } 
        else {

        }

    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

The code for the audio handler class as follows:

    package my.quotesbutton;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Player{

  public void fear() throws IOException{


    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("audio\\fear.wav");
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `fear.wav` cannot be found relative to the `Player` class. Try `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/fear.wav")`

Comment: What is line 221 of `QuotesButtonUI.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are passing `null` to the `AudioStream` constructor. The value you pass it is obtained via `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

From Java `Class` javadoc:

> `public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name)`
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:**
>   A `InputStream` object or `null` if no resource with this name is found

So, the way this could return `null` is that the file is not found. The problem is in your file path. The path you are passing is relative. Try finding where your application's work directory is and correct the path relative to it.

**EDIT:** You can get the working directory via `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.